# Bash shell iterating through directory doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash, for-loop, wildcard, glob, quotes

I am trying to iterate through a directory but the for loop doesn't work as expected. Look at this:

```
for dirname in "/dir_example/*"; do
    echo "$dirname"
done
```

What happens is that it only echos the string "/dir_example/*" and do not iterate over the directories. I tried it on another server and it worked. The shell is bash on the same computers. How is it possible?

Comment: It worked with bash on another computer? Are you sure of this? Please check twice: if it does, you found a bug in bash and it's time to report it (do not forget the bash version, the OS, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Globs like `*` are only expanded if they're unquoted. Luckily you can drop in and out of quotes in the same word:

```
for dirname in "/dir_example"/*; do
    echo "$dirname"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man, I found my mistake. There was a typo in the directory name on the different server (a directory that didn't exist), that's why the echo printed the string.